Launchd operation not permitted on mounted drives
I am trying to implement a script to perform rsync between two mounted drives on my MacOS (Monterey v12.7.3).
Before performing the sync, I try to cleanup old files using a find and delete command. When executing my script in terminal, it works just as expected.
However, when running the automated profile in batch, I get

Operation not permitted

Actually, I get the same if I launch a "ls -la" command on the mounted drives.
I found this fix, but it apparently didn't help. Am I missing another privilege?
Note: I've tried to add the scheduled script both to global LaunchDaemon and registered LaunchAgent - same result.
